# Laravel get request to hidden input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My website posts the id of a product to the url to show the correct data on the page, I want to grab this id to pass the value into a hidden input field to work with within the submitted forms controller.

Can I just grab the data from the url using a get request and store it into a hidden input field, which is sent along with the other form data.

Example -

```
<input type="text value="{{ Input::get('id') }}"
```

This is how my url looks -

```
http://mywebsite.app/admin/overview/10
```

Comment: Input::get('id); will only take the get-parameter. For example http://whatever.tld/horse/?id=39

Comment: Which version of Laravel do you use?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to get `10` from URL:

```
{{ Request::segment(3) }}
```

But this is bad practice. The good practice is to add parameter to a route, like:

```
Route:: get('admin/overview/{id}', 'SomeController@someAction');
```

Then you need to get it in `someAction()` and pass it to a view:

```
public function someAction ($id)
{
    ....
    return view('some.view', compact('id'));
}
```

And then just use `$id` variable `some.view`:

```
{{ $id }}
```